# Can we derive a Bolzano theorem for functions from the real line to groups?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, continuity

What if we have a function $f:\mathbb R \to \mathcal G$, where $\mathcal G$ is some group.

For what properties of $f$ can we derive the Bolzano theorem of [intermediate value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intermediate_value_theorem)?

Is it even meaningful to talk about such a thing?

Let us consider a simple group, rotations in the plane with matrix representation $$f:\phi \to \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi)&\sin(\phi)\\-\sin(\phi)&\cos(\phi)\end{bmatrix}$$

Here we should be able to prove that along the unit circle, we will have at least one solution.

$$\exists \phi_\xi :\phi_0\leq\phi_\xi\leq\phi_1 :f(\phi_\xi) = \begin{bmatrix}\cos(\phi_\xi)&\sin(\phi_\xi)\\-\sin(\phi_\xi)&\cos(\phi_\xi)\end{bmatrix}$$

But what about more general groups? What kind of concept of continuity will we need?

Comment: Is $\mathcal{G}$ a topological group?

Comment: @Keen-ameteur hmm, good question! I have not heard about topological groups until now.

Comment: @mathreadler If your group consists of matrices, then your group is indeed a topological group

Comment: @mathreadler In fact, your hypothesis is incorrect: you have forgotten to account for the possibility that the "path" described by $f$ goes the "other way" around the "circle".

Comment: @mathreadler That said, in a more generalized scenario, we find that any isolated points can be avoided as we could "weave around them." You might be interested in topological [fixed point theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_theorem), which can be thought of as a natural generalization to the intermediate value theorem.

Comment: @BenGrossmann No. That is something else. In the intermediate value theorem we consider an interval and if the function has a particular property (is continous) and some conditions are true on the endpoints, then we can say something about at least one point in between. It does not say anything whatsoever about points outside of this interval.

Comment: Think of the example $G = \mathbb R^2$.  This will give you plenty of counterexamples.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith Where can I read about this group? What is it's operation?

Comment: Simple vector addition.

Comment: @mathreadler If you prefer, you could think of the multiplicative group of matrices of the form
$$
\pmatrix{1&x_1\\&1\\&&1&x_2\\&&&1}, \quad x_1,x_2 \in \Bbb R.
$$
That said, the group of matrices given by
$$
\pmatrix{x_1&0\\0&x_2}, \quad x_1,x_2 > 0
$$
is isomorphic.